# How to call a nextflow (DSL2) module to run on several inputs without duplicating the code

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I was trying to collapse the following part of a workflow into something that doesn't require a duplication of code, if possible, note that the code as is works, just wanted to wrap it in a more concise way:
Here `splittingChannel_s1` and `splittingChannel_s2` are output of a previous channel and input to the current one.

```
include { ProcessA_Module as ProcessA_section1_Module} from './modules/Processes/module.nf'
include { ProcessA_Module as ProcessA_section2_Module} from './modules/Processes/module.nf'

workflow Pipeline {
    main:
//Section based workflow
        def vc_params_s1 = parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section1")  
        Channel_s1 = ProcessA_section1_Module(
            'sec1',
            vc_params_s1,
            splittingChannel_s1,
            reference,
            resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file1.txt"),
         resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file2.txt")
        )
        
        def vc_params_s2 = parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section2") 
        Channel_s2 = ProcessA_section2_Module(
            'sec2',
            vc_params_s2,
            splittingChannel_s2,
            reference,
            resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file1.txt"),
         resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file2.txt")
        )
    }
```

basically what i'd like to do would be to create one single call like:

```
Channel = ProcessA(
          ['sec1','sec2'],
          [vc_params_s1, vc_params_s2],
          [splittingChannel_s1,splittingChannel_s2],
          //these below are the same for both channels
          reference, 
          resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file1.txt"),
          resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file2.txt")
)
```

This code specifically returns a generic error such as: `workflow Pipeline {: unexpected input` so i am pretty sure this is not the way, Also, i would need to be able to call section 1 or section 2 out of `Channel`, which i also wouldn't know how to do,

I also tried a different solution, but it's more cumbersome and also returns the same error:

```
def Processes_variables = [
    'sec1': [
        type: 'section1',
        vc_params: parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section1"),
        splittingChannel: splittingChannel_s1
    ],
    'sec2': [
        type: 'section2',
        vc_params: parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section2"),
        splittingChannel: splittingChannel_s2
    ]
]

def ProcessedChannels = Processes_variables.collect { key, config ->
    createVariantCallingChannel(
        config.type,
        config.vc_params,
        config.splittingChannel,
        reference.,
        resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file1.txt"),
        resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file2.txt")
    )
}

// Access the module calls for nDNA and mtDNA
def Channel_sec1 = ProcessedChannels.find { channel ->
    channel.type == 'sec1'
}

def Channel_sec2 = ProcessedChannels.find { channel ->
    channel.type == 'sec2'
}
```

So, this latter, beside being syntactically wrong, it's start adding code more than prune it, which is not the purpose. what would be the appropriate way to avoid code duplication?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to combine the variable components into tuples, and then use the [`mix`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#mix) operator to combine the two channels. The following examples assumes that the `splittingChannel_s1` and `splittingChannel_s2` channels emit simple `file` objects, for example:

```
process my_proc {

    input:
    tuple val(section), val(vc_params), path(input_file)
    path reference
    path file1_txt
    path file2_txt

    output:
    tuple val(section), path("${input_file}.out")

    """
    touch "${input_file}.out"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    ...
    
    vc_params1 = parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section1")
    vc_params2 = parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section2")
    
    section1_ch = splittingChannel_s1.map { tuple( 'sec1', vc_params1, it ) }
    section2_ch = splittingChannel_s2.map { tuple( 'sec2', vc_params2, it ) }

    my_proc(
        section1_ch.mix( section2_ch ),
        reference,
        resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file1.txt"),
        resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file2.txt"),
    )

    my_proc.out
        .branch { section, outfile ->
            section1: section == "sec1"
            section2: section == "sec2"
        }
        .set { results }

    results.section1.view { section, outfile ->
        "Section1 results ${section}: ${outfile}"
    }
    results.section2.view { section, outfile ->
        "Section2 results ${section}: ${outfile}"
    }
```

Alternatively, if the number of elements in the tuple starts to become excessive, another way would be to feed in a [Map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#maps) object containing the required configuration properties, for example:

```
process my_proc {

    input:
    tuple val(config), path(input_file)
    path reference
    path file1_txt
    path file2_txt

    output:
    tuple val(config), path("${input_file}.out")

    """
    touch "${input_file}.out"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    ...

    def proc_config = [
        'sec1': [
            section_name: 'section1',
            vc_params: parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section1"),
        ],
        'sec2': [
            section_name: 'section2',
            vc_params: parameters.getSubParam("VC", "section2"),
        ]
    ]

    section1_ch = splittingChannel_s1.map { tuple( proc_config["sec1"], it ) }
    section2_ch = splittingChannel_s2.map { tuple( proc_config["sec2"], it ) }

    my_proc(
        section1_ch.mix( section2_ch ),
        reference,
        resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file1.txt"),
        resources.resolveOtherResourceFile("file2.txt"),
    )

    my_proc.out
        .branch { config, outfile ->
            section1: config.section_name == "section1"
            section2: config.section_name == "section2"
        }
        .set { results }

    results.section1.view { config, outfile ->
        "Section1 results ${config.section_name}: ${outfile}"
    }
    results.section2.view { config, outfile ->
        "Section2 results ${config.section_name}: ${outfile}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve, and after this, do you confirm that the section1_ch would be the output channel for 'section1' and section2_ch for section2? what i mean is, in the next step of my pipeline, can i call as inputs section1_ch and section2_ch? am i getting it right?

Comment: @Ulf90 Sorry it is not clear to me what the next step involves exactly. You can of course re-use those channels if that's what's needed. But assuming the next step takes either the section1 or section2 outputs of `my_proc` like in my examples (i.e. `my_proc.out`), you could use the [`branch`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#branch) operator, for example, to separate the outputs.

Comment: @Ulf90 I've added an example above using the branch operator, but please let me know if I've misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @Steve, indeed my need would be to then take the section1 output and section 2 output separately. So now in your example i can take the results.section1 and results.section2 as separate input channel for my next module, is that right? Many thanks man, you really know the stuff!

Comment: @Ulf90 Correct.